# Linux equivalent of windows startup folder

Tags: linux, boot, unix

I have a script that I want to run at startup for Linux, I know windows has a startup folder and that Linux has one as well. I've done some research and have found various files with many conflicting answers. The path:

```
/etc/systemd/system
```

seems to be used. Another one is:

```
/etc/rc.local
```

and I've also seen:

```
/etc/init.d
```

I just want the path for a Linux equivalent of a Windows startup folder that exists on all or at least most Linux distributions. I also want to be able to put a script in that directory to make it run at startup. What path can fulfill these requirements.

Comment: None. It's depended on your distribution and your system setup. Depending on your circumstances putting it in your local user bash/profile file might be an option.

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: My disto is Ubuntu 16.04.3

Answer (score 7):

Most forms of autostart depend on your installation: the init system you use (sysv vs systemd vs upstart), your desktop environment (GNOME/KDE vs non-XDG ones), etc.

Cron exists on most Linux systems, and can be used for autostart. Add a line to your `/etc/crontab`:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/blah
```

where `/usr/bin/blah` is the command you want to run.

If you want the program to start whenever you log in, and you are using a XDG-compliant desktop environment (e.g. GNOME or KDE), put a `.desktop` file into `~/.config/autostart`. For an example of a `.desktop` file, see the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_entries#File_example).

Alternately, if your Linux distro uses systemd, you can write an unit file. For example:

```
[Unit]
Description=autostart something

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/blah

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Put the above text into `/etc/systemd/system/blah.service` and run `systemctl daemon-reload` as root to register the service. Next, run `systemctl enable blah.service` to enable autostart of your new service.

For details on how to write a systemd unit file, see [this link](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html).